# Strategy for rotating objects with normal maps without screwing up lighting

Tags: pixi.js

I'm building a simulation with directional lighting where multiple sprites will be rendered in the scene. The sprites will be simple geometry layered with a normal map.

I'm using [this example](https://pixijs.io/examples/#/layers/normals.js) as a starting point for my code.

The problem is that if an object is rotated, the lighting within the scene no longer reflects off the normals on the rotated sprite correctly. For instance, lighting up the right-hand side of an object that is rotated by 180° will brighten the left-hand side of the object. I tested this by rotating block1 in the above example.

[image: No rotation.]

*No rotation.*

[image: 180° rotation.]

*180° rotation.*

I understand why this is happening. But I'm not sure how to approach resolving it. Is it possible to allow rotated normal maps to correctly reflect light? How?